# dart - I try to add item into my list using a function but the previous item got rewritten by the new item

Tags: flutter, dart, expandablelistview, flutter-listview

I tried making a growable list which will contain the salary that have been calculated from other pages. But when I tried to insert the latest salary into the list, the previous salary was rewritten as the latest added salary, so I ended up with 2 same item in the list. So I ended up with 2 same items inside the list. My objective here is to just make a screen with a growable list where the counter increases when I pushed the button from the previous page. Here is my code:

```
`class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  HistoryPage ({Key key, this.title}) : super(key : key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HistoryPageState createState() => _HistoryPageState();
}

class _HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  List<String> items = [];
  dynamic salary;
  dynamic counter = 0 ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    items = addItem(counter, salary);
    salary = globals.payment;
    counter = globals.counter;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
        title: Text("Your Salary History"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: counter,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(salary),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  List addItem(int counter, String salary) {
    setState(() {
      items = List.from(items)
        ..insert(counter, salary);
    }
    );
  }
}`
```

Here is the code for the page that increase the counter for my list:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/History/components/body.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/Payment/Components/background.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/PaymentDuration/paymentduration.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/globals.dart' as globals;

class PaymentSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // This size provide us total height and width of our screen
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "CALCULATE PAYMENT",
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return PaymentDuration();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "HISTORY",
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return HistoryPage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
                incrementCounter();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

int incrementCounter() {
  globals.counter = globals.counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: [Use a list.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? In my code, I did make a list, though I don't really understand how a list works as for now I tried inserting items inside an empty list which is growable. But when I insert a new item into the list, all the previous items in the list have the same value as the new list.

Comment: You use the `List.add` method to append the new element to the end of the list, for example `items.add(item)`. You should also know that `globals.counter = globals.counter + 1` is usually written as `globals.counter++`. You also don't need to keep a counter in the list. Use `items.length` to get the number of items.